# Asynchronous Sql Execution in .NET

Tags: c#, sql-server

In my Program I'm calling a Stored Procedure through asynchronous call

```
connection.Open();
IAsyncResult ar = cmd.BeginExecuteReader();
```

While executing the Page, If I click back button Page will be redirected to other page but the front-end objects cannot handle the back-end processing.

How can I stop running the Stored procedure?

Comment: If you want to get your questions answered, you need to start showing more respect to the community here and accept answers to your questions. Just go to your older questions and click the tick mark next to the answer that helped most.

Answer (score 0):

You should create `SqlTransaction` for the `SqlProcedure`, and cal the `Rollback()` method of it